In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to have it automatically switch to the Problems panel when a build produces errors?
In nearly every IDE I work in, when I compile some code and it produces errors, it will automatically display the bit of UI that lists any errors and warnings.
I'd like to do this in Visual Studio Code. I'm currently working in a CMake project, and every time I start a build, it switches to the Output panel and stays there, including when there's errors. It means I have to manually switch to the Problems panel each time to actually see and select an error.
It's a very minor annoyance, but it's one I hit hundreds of times a day so I'd like to change this behavior if possible. Can I have it just automatically select the Problems panel if there's a compiler warning or error?

For me the "problems" panel is showing the issues that are found by the code analyzer of the IDE even without building...

"In nearly every IDE I work in" - note: Visual Studio Code is very much not an IDE, it is an editor (and a fairly complex and user/beginner unfriendly one at that).

I think you can make a task in tasks.json with "type": "cmake", fill out the rest of the members like command, targets, group, and then in presentation, add "revealProblems": "onProblem", (related).

Even though "revealProblems" seems like it ought to do exactly what I want, when I create a CMake build task and then add that to its presentation settings, it has no effect. Also, looking at the issue you linked to and the related PR, it sounds like the problem panel should already be automatically revealed if there's a problem. I wonder why it's not working for me? My CMake Tools extension is fully up-to-date.

I figured it out. I also needed to add "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]
